LLM Studio fail to download model with error : unable to get local issuer certificate
In LLM studio, when I try to download any model, I am facing  following error:
Download Failed: unable to get local issuer certificate


I've experienced the same in a corporate network.
To get around I have been manually downloading through my browser (the url is to the left of the error message in your screenshot) and manually loading the models into the appropriate dir: ~/.cache/lm-studio/models in the appropriate subpath.
ie ~/.cache/lm-studio/models/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2-GGUF/mistral-7b-instruct-v0.2.Q6_K.gguf
Not the most elegant solution but I have yet to find information on a better workaround.

Ya I see this a lot with Docker & AppImage projects that do not allow custom CA/Certificate integration.  The application is expecting a direct connection to their https endpoint but this is not the case when behind a proxy.
Most likely you have a Firewall or MiTM type Proxy in place.
If you know how to add URL or HTTP Certificate Validation exceptions.
You could try adding these domains:
^([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\.)?lmstudio\.ai\.?/
^([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\.)?huggingface\.co\.?/
^([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\.)?hf\.co\.?/

Exception url's should get you past most LM Studio guff downloads...
